# Is it possible to combine switch case default and some of the case when they do the same thing

Tags: swift, xcode, switch-statement

I have a question about switch case in Swift.
I have a struct

```
struct State {
    static let initialized = "init"
    static let ready = "ready"
    static let recording = "recording"
    static let finished = "finished"
    static let error = "error"
}
```

and I want to return UIImage depending on the current State.

```
func getHeaderIconImage(from status: String) -> UIImage {
    var result = UIImage()
    switch status {
    case State.ready, State.finished:
        result = Images.ready
    case State.recording:
        result = Images.ongoing
    case State.initialized, State.error:
        result = Images.notReady
    default:
        result = Images.notReady
    }
    return result
}
```

Basically, the default part should not be triggered, but without the default part Swift will yelling at me with `Switch must be exhaustive` error, so I need to include the default case. Since I do the exact same thing for the .initialized, .error case, and the default case, probably it's better to combine those three parts and I should only write it down the default case. However, I though if I can also write the .initialized case and the .error case, it's more clear since I can list all the cases in the switch case.

So, I was wonderign if there is a way to refactor the switch state to combine the default case with some other cases if they do exactly the same thing? Or I cannot and either leave the .init & .error case and default, or get rid of the .init & .error part?

Comment: If you use an `enum` in place of the structure then you can omit the default case in the switch. The `enum` also appears to be more appropriate here.

Comment: Is `StreamState` really different from `State`? You use both in your second example but only list the first in the code. Do they really have unique `String` values?

Comment: @jnpdx sorry I forgot to delete the Stream part. Now I change the code. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: @liquid ahh, I didn't know that. Let me try with enum then! I'll get back to you once I fix the code!

Comment: Have a look at `fallthrough` in switch

Answer (score -1):

You are switching over a String value. The compiler doesn't know you are only using the static properties of your `State` struct, and technically you are not limited to that. So, in this case the compiler knows that other String values are possible and you need to add a `default` case. When you use an enum:

```
enum State: String {
    case initialized = "init"
    case ready = "ready"
    case recording = "recording"
    case finished = "finished"
    case error = "error"
}
```

The compiler knows all possible case and won't force you to use a `default` case.

Using the enum, your function should look like this:
`getHeaderIconImage(from status: State) -> UIImage`